# HttpRequest Credentials

Tags: c#, soap, httprequest

I want to use soap service, which receives xml data, and send too xml data.
In console application I get responce using this code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("SaopUrl");

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            string postData = @"query_xml=<MY-XML>";

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
            dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close ();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
            Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

But in response I receive not authorized. 
If I using html form action like this:

```
<form action="soapUrl" method="post" style="padding:0px">
<table cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <textarea name="query_xml" name="query_xml" cols="100" rows="30"></textarea>        
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I get good response. How to do it in C# using HttpRequest?

Answer (score 0):

[Visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) can help you with this